# interacting with background python script in PHP

Tags: php, python, background-process

I have some python code that use some library (sage). This python code is used as a script executed in PHP to generate a JSON that is transmitted to the webclient through AJAX. It is currently working, but very slowly (7s by request).

The reason is that for every request, the script load this huge library. So I change this script to only load the library once by PHP-session with an interactive input/output. Now, I need to launch the script in background once, and interact with it each time the client do a request. I tried with some named pipes without success. Is there a canonical way to achieve that ?

Thank you very much,

Comment: A simple socket communication would likely work well and easy.

Comment: So I should use socket communication between python and PHP ? is it hard to do ? I have trouble finding proper documentation on how to do that ...

Comment: It's the most basic way to do it. LMGTFY: https://docs.python.org/2/howto/sockets.html